# Read a webpage with R and xml

Tags: xml, r, utf-8

I am trying to get a dataframe to analyse it from this webpage [enter link description here](https://www.transparence.sante.gouv.fr/flow/rechercheEntreprises?execution=e3s4) (when you enter a name, you get a table with data)

I saved the code of the web page with note, but it's not seem to work

```
result <- xmlParse(file="mos.xml")
```

mos is the file with the web page code
I get the error message `Erreur : 1: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xE9 0x65 0x73 0x20`

I saw that i have to use `$content = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $content);
$xml = simplexml_load_string( utf8_encode($rss) );` to solve the problem but i dont know where to use it cause of the `$` 
Thank you

I tried also this method :

```
link <- "https://www.transparence.sante.gouv.fr/flow/rechercheEntreprises?execution=e7s3"
table = readHTMLTable(link, header=T, which=1,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

But i also get an error message